# Populate checked radio buttons from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have two sets of radio buttons i.e. two different inputs of upload form. Now I'm trying to make edit page but I'm stuck on populating already checked buttons on them.

First I select information from database

```
<?php
$sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM document_upload
        WHERE upload_id = ?                         
        LIMIT 1";

$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($upload_id));
$data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$title = $data['upload_title'];
$category = $data['category'];
$skills = $data['skills'];
$description = $data['description']; 
?>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="title">Title:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo !empty($title)?$title:'';?>">
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="description">Description:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description" value="<?php echo !empty($description)?$description:'';?>">
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="category">Category:</label>  
    <?php
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $sql="SELECT field_name FROM form_fields WHERE group_id=6";
        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row_category){
                echo '<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="category" value="'.$row_category['field_name'].'"> '. $row_category['field_name'].'</label>';                               
        }                                               
    ?>                          
</div>  
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="skills">Skills:</label>
        <?php
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $sql="SELECT field_name FROM form_fields WHERE group_id=7";
                foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row_skills){
                        echo '<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="skills" value="skills"> '. $row_skills['field_name'].'</label>';                                
                }                                               
        ?>                      
</div>
```

Title and Description are not the problem. They are populated fine.

I can't figured how to select all radio buttons available in database and then check which is selected.

Comment: here you need to set selected value display as checked in radio button. right?

Comment: Yes, must take it from database `$skills = $data['skills'];` and this `$category = $data['category'];` populated it and in the same time to show also all available options so if user want to change what is selected

Comment: I think you should use if($skills == $row_skills['field_name']) { $selected = "selected"; } else { $selected = ""; }

Comment: This inside `value=""`?

Comment: No, Value should be dynamic and use this : echo '<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="skills" value="'. $row_skills['field_name'].'"  ".$selected."> '. $row_skills['field_name'].'</label>';

Comment: But where to put this condition `if($skills == $row_skills['field_name']) { $selected = "selected"; } else { $selected = ""; }` above where I query database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109411/discussion-between-ruchish-parikh-and-bstud).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to check your radio buttons if value exist.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="category">Category:</label>  
    <?php
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $sql="SELECT field_name FROM form_fields WHERE group_id=6";
        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row_category){
            $checked= (isset($category) && $category == $row_category['field_name']) ?  "checked" : "";
            echo '<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="category" value="'.$row_category['field_name'].'" "'.$checked.'"> '. $row_category['field_name'].'</label>';                               
        }                                               
    ?>                          
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="skills">Skills:</label>
        <?php
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $sql="SELECT field_name FROM form_fields WHERE group_id=7";
                foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row_skills){
                    $checkedSkill = (isset($skills) && $skills == $row_skills['field_name']) ?  "checked" : "";
                    echo '<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="skills" value="'.$row_skills['field_name'].'" "'.$checkedSkill.'"> '. $row_skills['field_name'].'</label>';                                
                }                                               
        ?>                      
</div>
```